# Is there a non-Borel set with a positive Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Is there a non-Borel set with a positive Lebesgue measure?

My homework problem is to construct a non Borel set which is a union of uncountable disks(not a point) in $R^2$

Comment: Sorry, it is supposed to be uncountable union of closed disks(not a point).

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your **question** is yes, there is a non-Borel set of real numbers with positive Lebesgue measure. Let $A$ be some measurable non-Borel subset of $[0,1]$. Then $A\cup[3,8]$ is a non-Borel set of positive measure.

Here is a hint for your **homework problem**. Let $A$ be some non-Borel subset of $\mathbb R$. Then $A\times\{0\}$ is a non-Borel subset of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$. Find a set $S\subset\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ such that $S$ is the union of a family of closed disks, and the intersection of $S$ with the $x$-axis is equal to $A\times\{0\}$. You can do this by choosing, for each point $(x,0)\in A\times\{0\}$, a closed disk $D_x$ (of whatever size you like) whose intersection with the $x$-axis
 is $\{(x,0)\}$. Let $S=\bigcup\{D_x:x\in A\}$.

Then $S$ can't be a Borel set; if it were, then $S\cap(\mathbb R\times\{0\})=A\times\{0\}$ would be a Borel set.

Comment: Thank you. I still can't understand why S is not a Borel set. How to prove it?(..I forget to add a condition: the radius of all the disks is 1)